# ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: webdriver

I'm very new to WebDriver, and I'm just getting started on selenium. I followed the instruction on their pages, and when I tried to run my first project on Eclipse, I keep running to "ChromeDriver cannot resolved to a type". I have added all the selenium jars files in the classpath, and add executable path to chromedriver. I'd very appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
[This is my codes so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkmbl.png)

[I have added all the jars file in the order that is recommended by other answers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Omq.png)

Comment: "*I have added all the selenium jars files in the classpath*" **No, you haven't.** At least ```selenium-java.jar``` is missing.

Comment: it's a good practice to copy and paste the code into your question, not as an image. hence, the community can copy and paste to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the file selenium-java-3.141.59 and it only contains these 7 files, I also saw a selenium-java-4.00.00-alpha-7 that have a lot more files in it. I tried both of them and it still has that errors. Am I missing any steps along the ways?